# Sympy Solve returns an empty set

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I am trying to solve following polynomial equations using solve
However it returns an empty set.

```
    `3*d*x**2 + 2*w*x = 0,` 
    `3*d*y**2 + 2*w*y = 0,`
    `-d + 2*w*z + 1 =0,`
    `x**3 + y**3 - z = 0,`
    `x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1 = 0`
```

wolfram-alpha returns following real solutions.

```
    `d≈0.417238, w≈-0.516977, x = 0, y≈0.826031, z≈0.563624`
    `d≈0.417238, w≈-0.516977, x≈0.826031, y = 0, z≈0.563624`
    `d≈0.417238, w≈0.516977, x = 0, y≈-0.826031, z≈-0.563624`
    `d≈0.417238, w≈0.516977, x≈-0.826031, y = 0, z≈-0.563624`
    `d≈0.528689, w≈-0.492358, x≈0.620853, y≈0.620853, z≈0.478626`
```

How do I ensure that I get the solutions if they exist ?
Is there any other method with more robust handling of 0 and other conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SymPy as a paper-and-pencil enhancement and work through the equations as you would if you were solving them manually, you would find that the whole system can be reduced to a single polynomial expression which (in this case) has an explicit solution or could be solved numerically; the solutions for that single variable can then be back-susbtituted into the other equations. There are some [hints](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17186) that SymPy will one day solve such system more automatically, but I hope there is some joy in seeing the relationships for yourself as I did with the following:

Define the equations

```
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> eqs = (3*d*x**2 + 2*w*x,
... 3*d*y**2 + 2*w*y ,
... -d + 2*w*z + 1 ,
... x**3 + y**3 - z ,
... x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1 )
```

Look for a linear equation in some variable and solve it,
storing the solution

```
>>> reps=[(w,solve(eqs[0],w)[0])]
```

update the equations

```
>>> eqs=[i.subs(reps) for i in eqs]; eqs
[0, -3*d*x*y + 3*d*y**2, -3*d*x*z - d + 1, x**3 + y**3 - z, x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1]
```

repeat

```
>>> reps.append((d, solve(eqs[2],d)[0]))
>>> eqs=[i.subs(reps) for i in eqs]; eqs
[0, -3*x*y/(3*x*z + 1) + 3*y**2/(3*x*z + 1), -3*x*z/(3*x*z + 1) + 1 - 1/(3*x*z + 1), x**3 + y**3 - z, x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1]
>>> [cancel(i) for i in eqs]
[0, -(3*x*y - 3*y**2)/(3*x*z + 1), 0, x**3 + y**3 - z, x**2 + y**2 + z**2 - 1]

>>> reps.append((z, solve(eqs[-2],z)[0]))
>>> [cancel(i.subs(reps)) for i in eqs]
[0, -(3*x*y - 3*y**2)/(3*x**4 + 3*x*y**3 + 1), 0, 0, x**6 + 2*x**3*y**3 + x**2 + y**6 + y**2 - 1]

>>> reps.append((x, solve(eqs[1],x)[0]))
>>> [cancel(i.subs(reps)) for i in eqs]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 4*y**6 + 2*y**2 - 1]
```

until there is only 1 equation. It is cubic in `y**2` so there will be six solutions

```
>>> yy=solve(eqs[-1].subs(reps),y)
>>> [i.n(2) for i in yy]
[-0.62, 0.62, 0.55 - 0.71*I, 0.55 + 0.71*I, -0.55 - 0.71*I, -0.55 + 0.71*I]
```

Now build up the full solution for each y

```
>>> for i in yy:
...     sol=[(y,i)]
...     for v,e in reversed(reps):
...         sol.append((v,e.subs(sol).n(2)))
...     sol[0] = sol[0][0],sol[0][1].n(2)
...     print(sol)
[(y, -0.62), (x, -0.62), (z, -0.48), (d, 0.53), (w, 0.49)]
[(y, 0.62), (x, 0.62), (z, 0.48), (d, 0.53), (w, -0.49)]
[(y, 0.55 - 0.71*I), (x, 0.55 - 0.71*I), (z, -1.3 - 0.59*I), (d, -0.26 - 0.2*I), (w, 0.43 - 0.12*I)]
[(y, 0.55 + 0.71*I), (x, 0.55 + 0.71*I), (z, -1.3 + 0.59*I), (d, -0.26 + 0.2*I), (w, 0.43 + 0.12*I)]
[(y, -0.55 - 0.71*I), (x, -0.55 - 0.71*I), (z, 1.3 - 0.59*I), (d, -0.26 + 0.2*I), (w, -0.43 - 0.12*I)]
[(y, -0.55 + 0.71*I), (x, -0.55 + 0.71*I), (z, 1.3 + 0.59*I), (d, -0.26 - 0.2*I), (w, -0.43 + 0.12*I)]
```

This gets you well down the road to analyzing this equation set. The solutions that I built up are only for demonstration purposes; more accurate solutions would be obtained if you did not evaluate at each addition but waited until the end and then did `sol = {k:v.n(2) for k,v in sol}` before printing.

By working through the equations you find that basically you have 4 linear relationships and a polynomial in one variable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sympy's `solve` looks for fully symbolic solutions. The current version returns an empty list if the equations are too difficult to solve symbolically (without outputting an error nor a warning).

To obtain a numeric solution, sympy has `nsolve` which needs an initial guess, and (currently) only returns one solution.

```py
from sympy import nsolve, symbols

d, w, x, y, z = symbols('d w x y z', real=True)

nsolve([3 * d * x ** 2 + 2 * w * x,
        3 * d * y ** 2 + 2 * w * y,
        -d + 2 * w * z + 1,
        x ** 3 + y ** 3 - z,
        x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2 - 1], (d, w, x, y, z), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Reported solution:

```
Matrix([[ 0.528689459190352],
        [-0.492357687731282],
        [ 0.620853041008598],
        [ 0.620853041008598],
        [ 0.478626161989451]])
```